# Is there a way of taking advantage of this for privilege escalation

Tags: networking, windows-7, penetration-testing

penetration testing is a small hobby of mine, so I don't have a lot of experienced doing it. Keep that in mind when answering please.

I recently came across a network, where access to the C drive was blocked, so you couldn't access it by typing a path into Windows file manager, but there are some shortcuts on the desktop (which are the same and unchangeable for every standard user like me on the network), eg Photoshop, which if you do view file location on, you get into the C drive, and can navigate wherever you want. This made me think that that file viewer, which has access to the C drive has something special about it, and that I might be able to use it for some sort of privilege escalation, but being an amateur, I don't know if I'm correct, and I wouldn't be able to capitalise on it even if I was correct.

If someone could explain this to me, I would highly appreciate that. P.S.: the programming language I know best is python, and I have experience in using Kali Linux (I have a live bootable USB)

Comment: Also, it's in the tags, but just to make sure people know, this is on Windows 7

Comment: please clarify the environment. because networks don't have c drives to block. so where are you on the network. where is the cdrive you got access to and how does the network fit between you.

Comment: I believe this is on Windows 2003 server if that is what you mean